# Regex to parse youtube yid

Tags: php, regex, youtube

Example URLs

```
http://www.youtube.com/user/Scobleizer#p/u/1/1p3vcRhsYGo
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cKZDdG9FTKY&feature=channel
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yZ-K7nCVnBI&playnext_from=TL&videos=osPknwzXEas&feature=sub
http://www.youtube.com/ytscreeningroom?v=NRHVzbJVx8I
```

Any regex that will pull the correct YID from all 4 of these use cases? The first case is especially odd.

Thank you.

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube+regex

Comment: As far as I can tell, nobody else has handled my first test case.

Comment: Use them as examples and adapt. It's not *that* difficult.

Comment: I've updated [my regex answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830387/php-regex-find-all-youtube-video-ids-in-string/5831191#5831191) over on the: "[php regex - find all youtube video ids in string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830387/php-regex-find-all-youtube-video-ids-in-string)" question to handle these (new to me) YouTube URL syntaxes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
(?<=v=)[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+(?=&)|(?<=[0-9]/)[^&\n]+|(?<=v=)[^&\n]+
```

This works. https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7yXK.jpg

Comment: This needs to be modified to: `(?<=v=)[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+(?=&)|(?<=[0-9]/)[^&\n]+|(?<=v=)[^&\n]+` to allow for `_`

Comment: Had to add backslash for php `(?<=v=)[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+(?=&)|(?<=[0-9]\/)[^&\n]+|(?<=v=)[^&\n]+`

Answer (score 6):

For what it's worth, this worked on http://rubular.com/

```
(v=|\/)([\w-]+)(&.+)?$
```

Grabbing second capture group for these:

```
http://www.youtube.com/user/SilkRoadTheatre#p/a/u/2/6dwqZw0j_jY
http://youtu.be/6dwqZw0j_jY
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6dwqZw0j_jY&feature=youtu.be
http://youtu.be/afa-5HQHiAs
http://www.youtube.com/user/Scobleizer#p/u/1/1p3vcRhsYGo
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cKZDdG9FTKY&feature=channel
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yZ-K7nCVnBI&playnext_from=TL&videos=osPknwzXEas&feature=sub
http://www.youtube.com/ytscreeningroom?v=NRHVzbJVx8I
```

(the editor made me tab the URLs in as code, sorry)

Comment: Best regexp I've seen. You only have to check for match group 2 but it's pretty neat. BTW: This returns the id in match group 1 `[v=|\/]([\w-]+)(&.+)?$`