# preg_match() Unknown modifier '[' help

Tags: php, regex

I have this regex for getting the YouTube video ID:

```
(?<=v=)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?=&)|(?<=[0-9]/)[^&\n]+|(?<=v=)[^&\n]+
```

I get it from there: [Regex to parse youtube yid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597080/regex-to-parse-youtube-yid)

The problem is I get `preg_match() Unknown modifier '['` warning.

I know I have to enclose the regex delimiters but I have no idea how to do this.

Any help?

Comment: Add the forward slash delimiter within your regex

Comment: Did you delimit the regex in your code? i.e. `/expression/`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<?php
  $str = "http://www.youtube.com/ytscreeningroom?v=NRHVzbJVx8I";
  $pattern = '#(?<=v=)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?=&)|(?<=[0-9]/)[^&\n]+|(?<=v=)[^&\n]+#';
  preg_match($pattern, $str, $matches); 
  print_r($matches);
?>
```

Note, I'm using `#` as a delimiter here simply because the regular expression above contains forward slashes and escaping them makes the expression more difficult to read. This cleans it up by just a few pixels.

Comment: No you do not, I modified the code to reflect what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like delimiters: use [T-Regx library](https://t-regx.com), which works exactly like `preg_match()` but doesn't need delimiters.

```
$str = "http://www.youtube.com/ytscreeningroom?v=NRHVzbJVx8I";
$pattern = '(?<=v=)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?=&)|(?<=[0-9]/)[^&\n]+|(?<=v=)[^&\n]+';

//         ^ no delimiters :)                                          ^
```

and just use this

```
$match = pattern($pattern)->match($str)->first();
```

this results in

```
string(11) "NRHVzbJVx8I"
```