# preg_match_all: Warning: preg_match_all(): Unknown modifier '(' in

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [preg_match() Unknown modifier '[' help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011383/preg-match-unknown-modifier-help)

I am trying to match this pattern

```
 $regex_pattern = '<td id="(\w+)" class="(\w+)">(\w+).com<\/td>';
 preg_match_all($regex_pattern, $result, $matches);
 print_r($matches);
```

But I am getting this error: Warning: preg_match_all(): Unknown modifier '(' in

What's wrong in my regex pattern?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Add delimiters to your pattern](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)

When using the PCRE functions, it is required that the pattern is enclosed by delimiters. A delimiter can be any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character.

Often used delimiters are forward slashes (/), hash signs (#) and tildes (~).

```
 $regex_pattern = '/<td id="(\w+)" class="(\w+)">(\w+).com<\/td>/';
 preg_match_all($regex_pattern, $result, $matches);
 print_r($matches);
```