# Extract Video ID from youtube link in Javascript/Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery Youtube URL Validation with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964678/jquery-youtube-url-validation-with-regex)
>   [YouTube url id Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8388223/youtube-url-id-regex)

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SCS7SIeF30E

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SCS7SIeF30E&feature=relmfu

http://www.youtube.com/v/SCS7SIeF30E
```

How can I grab videoid `SCS7SIeF30E` from the above possible URL using javascript regular expression.

I know it has been asked many time but I am searching for Regex which cover 
v/ also in url all regex only covers v= type url.

Comment: This has been asked many times before. See the "Related" column or Stack Overflow's search

Comment: yep I know its posted but that regex work for only v=  while I have posted for regex which can be work with v/  like this

Comment: Then look at more than just one duplicate. [YouTube url id Regex](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8388223)

Comment: I provide a JavaScript regex solution to your question in [my popular answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5831191/433790) to a very similar question: [php regex - find all youtube video ids in string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5830387/433790)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var myString = "http://www.youtube.com/v/SCS7SIeF30E";

var newString = myString.replace(/http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/v\//, "");

alert(newString);
```

Comment: Syntax errors: `/` has to be escaped. Error in RegEx: `.` does not match a literal dot. Also, this method is very inflexible, and will not work for `watch`-URLs.

Comment: Yes, sorry about the '/'s. I had it working in FF scratchpad, but cut and paste changed it. HTH

Comment: I see the cause. Your code has to be formatted, by prefixing 4 spaces.